# Plot a .dat data set with pfgplots and substract the first values

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, csv

I would like to plot a .dat or .csv data set with tikz. The first column is the time and the second one the voltage. Since the data set is pretty huge, I already reduced its size by reading only every 100th value of it. To do this, I use gnuplot as you can see below. I measured the data set with an oscilloscope and therefore an offset for the x-and y-coordinate exists. My Problem is now to substract this offset like "$1-firstvalueofthiscolumn" (the offset is to be subtracted from each value in the column).  It is already possible to substract a fixed value like "$1-0.1", but since I have a lot of data files it takes a lot of effort to find out every offset. Is there any way to read the first column value of the data file and substract this one?

My idea was here to read the data file before and save the first value of each column as a variable which I can use later on when plotting. But unfortunately I didn't manage to get that one running.

I am very thankful for any help

Edit:
I've uploaded the measured data set from the oscilloscope here:
https://www.filemail.com/d/qtulzcvctxmtleh

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
        plot "Test/rising_edge_cap.dat" using ($1):($2) every 100; 
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there really no one who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, could you include a (very) small amount of sample data with `\usepackage{filecontents}` - see:https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: This is probably not what you want!? `using ($2-$1):($3)`

Comment: No not quite. I want to have something like `plot "Test/rising_edge_cap.da" using ($1-$[firstelement]):($2-$2[firstelement]) every 100`. Sorry for the long response time but I had to wait for the support to merge my accounts

Comment: I believe that is what is in my answer!? - just add `every 100`

Comment: yep correct. I just answered this one first. Thank you again hpekristiansen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not provide any data other than an external link, I just made some random numbers. The plot is moved, so that it start in `(0,0)` - that is what I am guessing you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
10 1000
22 2369
33 3837
44 6819
55 7124
66 4849
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [red, mark=*] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {plot "\jobname.dat"  using 1:2 };
\addplot [green, mark=*] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {plot "\jobname.dat"  using ($0==0?(offsetx=$1)-offsetx:$1-offsetx):($0==0?(offsety=$2)-offsety:$2-offsety) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red random plot. Green is the same plot, but offset to start in 0,0]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)